# Can I remotely control multiple OpenWrt routers simultaneously?

Tags: openwrt, open-source, remote-installation

Is it possible to control router settings and send instructions from a remote server (specifically related to guest access settings) to multiple routers running OpenWrt firmware at the same time?

Comment: What did you try? Do you know how to remotely control a single router?

Comment: No I cannot.However I am exploring the possible options that would help me do so in regards to a project.So would this firm ware provide me with that option .If so are there any preconditions for doing so.And if it does can I control guest access settings on the routers remotely ?

Answer (score 1):

1. OpenWISP can implement remote configuration at the operative center. But it need to customize openwrt firmware which use bash shell to get config from server.
   Please refer to http://openwisp.org/whatis.html.
2. Ansible can also do something about this. But it need to install python on device. http://www.ansible.com/

Comment: openwisp2 doesn't need too much customization, check it out: https://github.com/openwisp/ansible-openwisp2

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box tool I've ever heard of that will let you add a list of OpenWRT routers and issue commands to each one.

However, if I'm not mistaken, you can issue "LuCi" commands via SSH to modify parameters, or something similar on OpenWRT.  There are tools that let you issue commands to multiple SSH servers in parallel (google "Parallel SSH") and that might help you.