# What's the best way of controlling Wifi routers and access points?

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, openwrt, upnp

I want to add support for controlling Wifi routers/access points on the local network. The first device I plan to add support for uses OpenWRT and from the question [Can I remotely control multiple OpenWrt routers simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/915866/can-i-remotely-control-multiple-openwrt-routers-simultaneously) it seems like I can do this via "LuCi" commands over SSH. But is there some other method that will work with other routers using different firmware? I thought of [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) but it's usually turned off by default.

Comment: uPnP isn't a protocol that control or configures wireless. It's so routers can open ports automatically. Why are you trying to do this? If you have a sufficiently large enough network to justify a management solution for more than a few routers, purchase a system that is made to actually do this like Ubiquiti or OpenMesh.

Comment: OpenWrt has its own "controller", OpenWISP.

Comment: I'm not trying to control multiple routers at the same time, I'm trying to control one router but handle as many variations as I can. OpenWISP seems a bit heavy.